# Выборка элементов из таблицы mysql по приоритету

Tags: php, mysql

Предположим что есть какой-то товар и цена к нему. Цена меняется с определенной периодичностью, которая есть в таблице. Необходимо реализовать возможность, чтобы администратор мог ввести новую цену на продукт и поставить интервал времени, когда эта цена будет актуальна. При этом если админ укажет две цены на один и тот же товар, на сайте должна быть показана цена, которая имеет наименьший интервал.
Пример:
С 10.01.2018 по 10.02.2018 администратор ставит цену в 800$.
С 15.01.2018 по 25.01.2018 он ставит цену в 750$.
На сайте показана цена в 750$ если сегодня 23.01.2018

Comment: Если необходимо, то реализуйте, это не биржа наемного труда. Здесь помогают решить вопрос, а у вас его нет.

Comment: Так вопрос в том, как поставить приоритет в выборке. Как раз прошу помочь решить вопрос. Как это лучше сделать

Comment: Обычно вопросительное предложение заканчивается знаком вопроса, у вас я его, к сожалению, не заметил. Но ближе к делу - делаете выборку цен по текущей дате, и из них выбираете минимальную. ну или можно всё одним запросом сделать - SELECT min(price) from product_prices where productId = :productId AND start_date <= now() and now() <= end_date

Comment: 1) Выбрать записи со всеми ценами, подходящими для сегодняшнего дня 2) Из полученных результатов выбираете тот, у которого интервал меньше

Comment: @DanielProtopopov такой запрос можно использовать, если точно известно что цена в короткий период более низкая.

Comment: Благодарю, Антон. Теперь я понял как сделать

Comment: Да, мой запрос скорее для извлечения минимальной цены на сегодня, нежели чем возможность "реализации", под которой не понятно что подразумевается.